# Ruby on Rails extending a gem's class and changing its inheriting class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, extending-classes, impressionist

I have a web app built on Ruby on Rails.
In this app obviously use different Gems.
Iv come to a point where i want to extend some specific gem's classes, and add methods to it.

Now i have a use case where i want to extend a gem's class, but instead of adding methods, i want to change its inherting class
lets take the Impressionist Gem for example:

Iv created a new class in my app - app/models/impression.rb

```
class Impression < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(ENV[App_LOGS_DB'])
end
```

i want to change the Inheritance to use a my custom class called LogsBase

```
class Impression < LogsBase
end
```

the LogsBase class is definend as follows:

```
class LogsBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection ENV['APP_LOGS_DB']
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

When in try to run the server, the following exception is raised:

```
/gems/impressionist-1.6.1/lib/impressionist/models/active_record/impression.rb:5:in `<main>': superclass mismatch for class Impression (TypeError)
```

which from my understanding basically means there is a conflict between the gem's impression class definition and my own extention of that class.

Can anyone please help in finding out a way that i can change the Impression class inherting class, while still perserving the class's behaviour and making my server run properly?

PS: the goal of all this is to write the impressions data into a different database (logs db) rather than the main app db. in order to do that i need to establish a connection to the logs db, but if ill do it within the Impression class directly , it will blow up my pool of DB connections as indicated in the following link:

https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/managing-multiple-databases-in-a-single-rails-application/

thats why i need the abstract LogsBase class.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider making a PR to the gem, to allow the base class to be configured. (And then use your fork in the meantime.)

Comment: It would be helpful to include a link to the library in question: https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/blob/master/lib/impressionist/models/active_record/impression.rb

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: **do not do that!**

The only way I can think of is a nasty hack, neither reliable, nor robust, that is not compatible with newer versions of your external gem. Since Ruby does not allow to redefine the classes ancestors, you might (**but please don’t**):

1. grab the content of original `/gems/impressionist-1.6.1/lib/impressionist/models/active_record/impression.rb` file.
2. copy-paste it into your `/blah/foo/impression`.
3. make your class be loading `impressionist/models/active_record/impression` explicitly.
4. in the very second line of the file *unset original class*.

Something like this:

```
require 'impressionist/models/active_record/impression'

Object.send :remove_const, 'Impression'

class Impression < LogsBase
  # ORIGINAL CONTENT OF THIS FILE
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no (sensible) way to redefine a base class in ruby. It's *possible*, but only via weird hacks.

I would suggest taking one of two routes here:

1. Fork the library, and make the base class configurable (with backwards compatibility).
2. Don't do this via inheritance. Instead, put `establish_connection ENV['SPLACER_LOGS_DB']` into a **module**, and `include` it in the class.

I would be inclined to use option 2 for now, as it's a quick/simple workaround that should fit well with the rest of the application.

Comment: Regarding suggestion 2:
Will calling the establish_connection method within a **module** and including it within my **model** will achieve the same goal of preventing reaching pool threshold as if i use **inheritance**?
im not really sure it will... (or how can i test it for that matter)

Comment: @zivaricha If inheritance works, then module inclusion will work. If inheritance fails, then module inclusion will fail too. I'm not entirely sure how you could best test it either, but I can at least say the behaviour will be the same.

Comment: @zivaricha to expand on this. Your concern about the pooling is unnecessary if `Impression` is the only class calling establish connection in this fashion. Do you have other classes that would inherit from  `LogsBase`?

Comment: @TomLord Gotcha, ill give it a try.
engineersmnky, i have 8 other classes that establish a connection to a different DB same way the impression class suppose to.
And all of these classes get hit very often, thats why I'm concerned.

Comment: @zivaricha If you have 8 other classes with this behaviour, then all the more reason to move it into a module anyway! :)